# Regex help to filter unexpected string

Tags: regex

Sorry, I didn't make my quest clear. In the code comment, I hope the first string match=true, and the second string match=false. With the current Regex, both return true.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create a REGEX String 
    // Solved: I should use "^/apps/[^/]*/config.*"
    String REGEX = "^/apps/.*/config.*"; 

    // creare the string 
    // in which you want to search 
    //this one match
    String actualString = "/apps/test/config.author.dev"; 

    //I need this one doesn't match
    //String actualString = "/apps/test/test/config.author.dev"; 

    // compile the regex to create pattern 
    // using compile() method 
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX); 

    // check whether Regex string is 
    // found in actualString or not 
    boolean matches = pattern 
                          .matcher(actualString) 
                          .matches(); 

    System.out.println("actualString "
                       + "contains REGEX = "
                       + matches); 
}
```

Comment: It is not quite clear the pattern that you trying to match with the regex. Can you give more info? Why isn't the regex "/apps/wm/config/test/test" enough?

Comment: It appears the string must represent a qualified file name, must begin `'/apps/'`, `'/config'` must immediately precede `'/test/test'`, the latter begin at the end of the string and `'/test'` may not appear between `'/apps/'` and `'/config'`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that what you mean is that the string represents some sort of file path, and the "config.author.dev" file must be inside the "apps" folder, but with only one folder between them.

Well, this regex `^/apps/[^/]*/config.*` can garantee that no other slash ("/") must exist in the string that separates the "/apps/" from "/config". The "^" means "not the following characters" when inside and at the start of [].

Answer (score 0):

Here is another similar solution to @Pedro Pinheiro . It addresses the problem when you want to count something in a string.
`^/apps/[^/]*(?:/\w+){0,0}[^/]*/config.*`

Changing the numbers `{0,0}` it is possible to specify  max numbers or min count for /